# Identifying cause of differing drive in similar situations

Tags: cognitive-psychology, motivation

I am a software developer. I absolutely love what I do and I am very good at it. I have a strong work ethic. When I go to work, I work the full time, I am highly productive and engaged for the entire period. I will even get so into the work that I will happily work longer than normal to finish products. It is fun for me to work.

I have also been trying to start my own business by creating my own software solution by working whenever I have free time. However, trying to get myself to do this work is painful. I almost never want to do it and I will procrastinate like crazy. I am 1% as productive when working on my own projects.

While I suspect this has something to do with being owent to others, I am curious if there is any research on this area? If so, what is it called and what are some of the best papers too look at to start understanding/controlling drive?

Comment: [Motivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation) would be a good place to start.